# Validation of Roman Numerals! (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, roman-numerals

I have written a Java program to convert roman numerals into numbers. My only problem is if somebody enters `"IIII"` it shows up as 4, but instead it should give an error that it is not a valid roman numeral. I need to include the following rules into my code. Could anybody help me with this?

**(1) No digit is repeated in succession more than thrice, i.e., I, X and C cannot be repeated more than 3 times.**

**(2) The digits V, L and D are not repeated. The repetition of V, L and D is invalid in the formation of numbers.**

Comment: playing Devils advocate : iiii is in fact a correct Roman number for 4. https://monochrome-watches.com/why-do-clocks-and-watches-use-roman-numeral-iiii-instead-of-iv/

Comment: Sure, but another example would be "VVVV" this is not a roman numeral, or somebody inputting "VV" instead of "X"

Comment: Just as a friendly reminder: StackOverflow's language is english, and having non-english method or variable names can make it hard to read and comprehend the code.

Comment: Your goodwill is appreciated. Next time consider doing a Search+Replace in your actual code example. Thank you.

Comment: So `x.indexOf("IIII")` must be less than `0`, right? Could you do the rest?

Comment: There are more rules to check for a valid Roman numeral than the two you specified.  It's probably easier to convert the Roman numeral to a decimal number and then convert the decimal number back into a Roman numeral.  Finally, compare the input Roman numeral with the converted Roman numeral and see if they're the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Conversion of Roman number to Decimal number:**

```
public class RomanNumberUtils {
        static String romanNumeral;
        static int decimalNum;
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                RomanNumberUtils roman = new RomanNumberUtils();
                roman .convertRomanToDecimal();
                roman .printRoman(romanNumeral);
        }
 
        public void convertRomanToDecimal () {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter a Roman number: ");
                romanNumeral = scan.nextLine();
                romanNumeral = romanNumeral.toUpperCase();
                
                int l=  romanNumeral.length();
                int num=0;
                int previousnum = 0;
                for (int i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
                { 
                        char x =  romanNumeral.charAt(i);
                        x = Character.toUpperCase(x);
                        switch(x)
                        {  
                                case 'I':
                                previousnum = num;
                                num = 1;
                                break;
                             case 'V':
                                     previousnum = num;
                                num = 5;
                                break;
                                case 'X':
                                        previousnum = num;
                                num = 10;
                                break;
                                case 'L':
                                        previousnum = num;
                                num = 50;
                                break;
                                case 'C':
                                        previousnum = num;
                                num = 100;
                                break;
                                case 'D':
                                        previousnum = num;
                                num = 500;
                                break;
                                case 'M':
                                        previousnum = num;
                                num = 1000;
                                break;
                        }           
                        if (num<previousnum)
                        {decimalNum= decimalNum-num;}
                         else
                        decimalNum= decimalNum+num;
                }
        }
        public static void printRoman (String romanNumeral){
                System.out.println ("The equivalent of the Roman numeral "+romanNumeral+" is "+decimalNum);
        }
}
```

Comment: A **pre-validation** is required to validate roman text (characters) that means any roman number should not contains any character more than 3 times in consecutive (roman characters :  I, V, X,L,C,D,M)

Comment: Hi, the only problem with that many horizontal space is that the code quickly gets out of the window

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of a Roman numeral to decimal number converter.

Here are the test results from one of my many tests.

```
Enter a Roman numeral: ccccllllxxxxvvvviiii
The input Roman numeral CCCCLLLLXXXXVVVVIIII is invalid.
The correct Roman numeral is DCLXIV.
The decimal value is 664.
Enter a Roman numeral: mcmlxxii
The input Roman numeral MCMLXXII is valid.
The decimal value is 1972.
Enter a Roman numeral: mmmccclll
The input Roman numeral MMMCCCLLL is invalid.
The correct Roman numeral is MMMCDL.
The decimal value is 3450.
Enter a Roman numeral: mcmlxxio
The input Roman numeral MCMLXXIO contains invalid characters.
Enter a Roman numeral: lcl
The input Roman numeral LCL is invalid.
The correct Roman numeral is CC.
The decimal value is 200.
Enter a Roman numeral: quit
```

Basically, I converted the input Roman numeral into a decimal number.  Then I converted the decimal number back into a Roman numeral.  I compared the Roman numerals, and output the correct Roman numeral along with the decimal value.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RomanNumeralConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RomanNumeralConversion rnc = new RomanNumeralConversion();
        rnc.processRomanNumerals();
    }
    
    private Object[][] conversion = { { 1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 
            50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1 },
            { "M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", 
            "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I" } };
    
    public void processRomanNumerals() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputRomanNumeral = readRomanNumeral(scanner);
        
        while (!inputRomanNumeral.equals("QUIT")) {
            int value = convertToDecimal(inputRomanNumeral);
            if (value < 0) {
                System.out.println("The input Roman numeral " + 
                        inputRomanNumeral + " contains invalid characters.");
            } else {
                String calculatedRomanNumeral = convertToRoman(value);
                
                if (inputRomanNumeral.equals(calculatedRomanNumeral)) {
                    System.out.println("The input Roman numeral " + 
                            inputRomanNumeral + " is valid.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The input Roman numeral " + 
                            inputRomanNumeral + " is invalid.");
                    System.out.println("The correct Roman numeral is " + 
                            calculatedRomanNumeral + ".");
                }
                System.out.println("The decimal value is " + value + ".");
            }
            inputRomanNumeral = readRomanNumeral(scanner);
        }
        
        scanner.close();
    }

    private String readRomanNumeral(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print("Enter a Roman numeral: ");
        return scanner.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
    }
    
    private int convertToDecimal(String input) {
        int output = 0;
        int index = 0;
        
        while (index < input.length()) {
            boolean isInvalid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < conversion[1].length; i++) {
                String test = (String) conversion[1][i];
                int j = index + test.length();
                if ((j <= input.length()) && 
                        (input.substring(index, j).equals(test))) {
                    output += (Integer) conversion[0][i];
                    index = j;
                    isInvalid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (isInvalid) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        
        return output;
    }
    
    private String convertToRoman(int input) {
        String output = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < conversion[0].length; i++) {
            int value = (Integer) conversion[0][i];
            if (input >= value) {
                output += (String) conversion[1][i];
                input -= value;
                i--;
            }
        }
    
        return output;
    }

}
```